# How to setup JDO in tomcat 8 correctly?

Tags: h2, jdo, datanucleus, tomcat8

I had a setup which worked correctly as Java application (at least from Eclipse) and I am reusing this code to access data from a (simple) Vaadin application deployed in tomcat.

Despite reading and re-reading Tomcat 8 and DataNucleus documentation and searching, I fail to set all up correctly as it seems I cannot articulate the documentations with another.

I am using **Eclipse, Tomcat 8, DataNucleus 4.1 and H2 DB** and am not a master in any.
It is most certainly a configuration issue in Tomcat, DataNucleus or both.

I let Eclipse build the project to "Run on Server".

The errors I get are the following :

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:866)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1104)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:924)
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.configureData(VaadinFromJDO.java:102)
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.init(VaadinFromJDO.java:61)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:675)
```

[...]

```
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: You have either specified for this PMF to use a "persistence-unit" of "AeroLogbook" (yet this doesnt exist!) or you called JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory with "AeroLogbook" as the name of a properties file (and this doesnt exist in the CLASSPATH)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:455)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:307)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1970)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1171)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:849)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1104)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:924)
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.configureData(VaadinFromJDO.java:102)
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.init(VaadinFromJDO.java:61)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:675)
```

[...]

```
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
No "persistence.xml" file was found in the CLASSPATH. These files should be found under the META-INF/ directory in the root of a CLASSPATH entry/jar.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: No "persistence.xml" file was found in the CLASSPATH. These files should be found under the META-INF/ directory in the root of a CLASSPATH entry/jar.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.getMetaDataForPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2238)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:439)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:307)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1970)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1171)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:849)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1104)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:924)
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.configureData(VaadinFromJDO.java:102)
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.init(VaadinFromJDO.java:61)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:675)
```

[...]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.configureData(VaadinFromJDO.java:115)
    at com.xxxx.aerologbook.VaadinFromJDO.init(VaadinFromJDO.java:61)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:675)
```

Yet my file tree looks like this (I edited to remove dirnames and build paths):

```
AeroLogBook $ ls -R1
ivy.xml
ivysettings.xml

./Resources:
LogBook_FULL.out.xml
LogBook_FULL.xml

./WebContent/META-INF:
**MANIFEST.MF**

./WebContent/VAADIN/themes/aerologbook:
addons.scss
aerologbook.scss
styles.scss

./WebContent/WEB-INF:
**context.xml
web.xml**

./WebContent/WEB-INF/lib:
datanucleus-api-jdo-4.1.1.jar
datanucleus-core-4.1.3.jar
datanucleus-jdo-query-4.0.4.jar
datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.3.jar
h2-1.4.188.jar
jdo-api-3.1.jar
log4j-core-2.3.jar
logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
logback-core-1.1.3.jar
serializer.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
xalan.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis.jar

./src:
logback.xml

./src/META-INF/services:
package.jdo
**persistence.xml**

./src/com/xxxx/aerologbook:
VaadinFromJDO.java

./src/com/xxxx/aerologbook/backend:
Aircraft.java
Flight.java
FlightTime.java
LogBook.java

./src/com/xxxx/aerologbook/backend/enums:
AircraftOperation.java
FlightOperation.java
FlightRules.java
PilotOperation.java

./src/com/xxxx/aerologbook/core:
FlightRowCheck.java

./src/com/xxxx/aerologbook/stats:
AeroStats.java

./src/com/xxxx/aerologbook/xineo:
XAircraftType.java
XDate.java
XFlight.java
XFlightTime.java
XLogBook.java
XineoTransformHelper.java

./src/com/xxxx/aerologbook/xineo/enums:
XFlyingType.java
XPilotFunction.java
```

**getPersistenceFactoryManager** is called here (in VaadinFromJDO.java):

```
    private void configureData() {
        log.debug("Getting the data to be displayed");
        PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = null;
        PersistenceManager pm = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        Iterator<Flight> it = null;

        log.debug("Try to create the JDO resources");
        try {
            // Create a PersistenceManagerFactory for this datastore
            pmf = **JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("AeroLogbook")**;
            pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
            tx = pm.currentTransaction();
        }
```

**web.xml** contains only the servlet definition and servlet-mappings and this one it seems I figured out as the Servlet is called

**package.jdo** contains the classes relationships and works ok from the Java application

**MANIFEST.MF** is empty

**persistence.xml** contains this (which is working in the Java application)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <!-- Tutorial "unit" -->
    **<persistence-unit name="AeroLogbook">**
        <class>com.xxxx.aerologbook.backend.LogBook</class>
        <class>com.xxxx.aerologbook.backend.Aircraft</class>
        <class>com.xxxx.aerologbook.backend.Flight</class>
        <class>com.xxxx.aerologbook.backend.FlightTime</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR H2 -->
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:~/AeroLogbook" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value="" />
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="h2" />
            <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I also tried to create a **context.xml** which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource name="AeroLogbook" auth="Application"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     description="Aero Log Book"/>
  <ResourceParams name="AeroLogbook" type=javax.sal.DataSource>
    <parameter>
        <name>url</name>
        <value>jdbc:h2:~/AeroLogbook</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <name>driverClassName</name>
        <value>org.h2.Driver</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <name>username</name>
        <value>sa</value>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <name>password</name>
        <value></value>
    </parameter>
  </ResourceParams>
</Context>
```

1/ Is the **context.xml** needed ? (I was trying to use it instead of persistence.xml)

2/ Where to put the **persistence.xml** to make things work ?

3/ Is there anything else that could me missing ?

Comment: "context.xml" is nothing to do with JDO. "persistence.xml" has to be at META-INF/persistence.xml from the root of the CLASSPATH so wherever Tomcat puts things ... that's all JDO cares about (just like JPA, since JDO follows JPA conventions on that). Look at http://javahowto.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/where-to-put-persistencexml-in-web-app.html

Comment: thanks, I have to sort through other errors but it seems to work now